# Getting sprite to follow mouse, weird glitch when using views

Tags: c++, sfml

I was wondering if anyone could help me. My sprite was following my mouse fine until i started using views i am just starting using SFML, to make the sprite follow my player i used this.

```
void player::rotateToMouse(sf::Sprite &sprite, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{       
    this->mouse = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);


    const float PI = 3.14159265;

    float a = playerPosition.x - mouse.x;
    float b = playerPosition.y - mouse.y;

    mouseAngle = (atan2(b, a)) * 180 / PI; 

    playerSprite.setRotation(mouseAngle + 180);

}
```

I am adding this code in my update method, like so,

```
void player::update(sf::RenderWindow &window){


    this->rotateToMouse(playerSprite, window);
    this->followPlayer();
```

I am setting my views like this,

```
void player::followPlayer(){

    view.reset(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 32 + 10, 32 + 10));


    view.zoom(15);


    view.setCenter(playerSprite.getPosition());

}
```

and my movement code is this,

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
    playerSprite.move(std::cos(3.14159265 * mouseAngle / 180.f)  * speed  *-1, std::sin(3.14159265 * mouseAngle / 180.f) * speed  *-1);
}
else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)){                              //Speed
    playerSprite.move(std::cos(3.14159265 * mouseAngle / 180.f)  * speed , std::sin(3.14159265 * mouseAngle / 180.f)  * speed );
}

this->playerPosition = playerSprite.getPosition();
```

I can see the sprite is facing slightly off and after a while he starts to spin round randomly, i am quite a noob at c++ and if anyone could help me it would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to add 'c++' etc in the title, just add them directly as 'tags'. Tags are usually displayed along with the title, so that's spurious and actually considered bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`sf::RenderTarget::mapPixelToCoords`](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a2b0cab0e4c6af29d4efaba149d28116d). Basically you need to change how you compute the mouse position from:

```
this->mouse = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
```

to

```
this->mouse = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
```

Comment: @DaedricWolf: "solved" here means "accepting" an answer. Big green "V" under the +-1 scoring buttons to the left. Btw. pay careful attention to the "map coords" topic. Basically, it's just an offset between local/inner and parent/outer coordinates of a view/frame/rectangle/window/control/etc, whatever your UI hierarchy is. Really important in graphics, screen layout and UI/Input event handling. Sorry, seems I'm getting chatty. Bye now:)